# How to fetch first column from given powershell array?

Tags: powershell

There is a command which executes and give me the following output

```
Customer ID Client Name Computer Name Computer Brand
123        user1    127.0.0.1  lenovo
1          user2    127.0.0.2  apple
86         user3    127.0.0.1  dell
21         user4    127.0.0.4  apple
```

I want to get the `Customer ID` of users who use `Computer Brand` apple. The output should be as follows, so that I can do further operations on those ID's:

```
1
21
```

I tried to first select the users with 'apple' using the following:

```
$output | Select-String -pattern 'apple'
```

but then it will just print users with 'apple', but not the first row which makes it difficult for me to process further.

### Update

I do not know if the following helps.

```
PS> $output.GetType();

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing basic PowerShell concepts of the cmdlets [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-5.1) and [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1)

```
#simulating $output
$output = @"
Customer ID,Client Name,Computer Name,Computer Brand
123,user1,127.0.0.1,lenovo
1,user2,127.0.0.2,apple
86,user3,127.0.0.1,dell
21,user4,127.0.0.4,apple
"@ -split '\r?\n' | ConvertFrom-Csv

$output | Where 'Computer Brand' -eq 'apple' | Select-Object 'Customer ID'
```

Sample output:

```
Customer ID
-----------
1
21
```

**EDIT** just in case your output isn't an object but pure text, try this

```
$output -replace '\s{2,}',',' | Select -skip 1 | 
  Convertfrom-Csv -Header 'Customer ID','Client Name','Computer Name','Computer Brand' | 
    Where 'Computer Brand' -eq 'apple' | Select-Object 'Customer ID'
```

Or simpler

```
($output | sls '^(\d+).*apple').Matches|% {$_.groups[1].value}
```

Comment: The output is not CSV. It is as I have shown in the question.

Comment: Guess what the comment `#simulating data` is meant for? I'll replace `$Data` with `$output` to be easier to understand.

Comment: hmm strange, it is giving me no output. Also, you are missing single quote for closing Computer Brand. Also, I will not need "Customer ID"

Comment: The first one gave me the output with "Customer ID" which I do not want. The simpler one gives me the output that I wanted. Now, I need to do some operation on those ID's as `do some work on ID`

Comment: To omit the header in the 1st, change the `Select` to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Customer ID'`

Answer (score 1):

If we assume `$output` is an object with the properties listed in your header, then you can do the following to access the `Customer ID` value:

```
$output.where({$_.'Computer Brand' -eq 'apple'}).'Customer ID'
```

The following will list the all of the properties for the object that has the targeted `Computer Brand`:

```
$output.where({$_.'Computer Brand' -eq 'apple'})
```

If `$output` is already an array with lines of text, you can do something like the following:

```
$output = ($output | Select-Object -skip 1) -replace "\s+","," |
             ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'Computer ID','Client Name','Computer Name','Computer Brand'

$output.where({$_.'Computer Brand' -eq 'apple'}).'Customer ID'
```

Answer (score 0):

this might come in handy:

```
((query user) -replace ">","") -replace "  {2,}","`t" |ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" |select -ExpandProperty USERNAME
```

This gives back a list of currently logged on users. Only the USERNAME column, no headers.