# How to convert powershell array to table

Tags: powershell

I found a similar post regarding the problem in the link below.

[How to fetch first column from given powershell array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57508154/how-to-fetch-first-column-from-given-powershell-array)

I am not able to directly convert it to a table as some fields are missing and do operations.

```
Customer ID        Client Name        Computer Name        Computer Brand        Duration        Connection Time        Lang
123                first last         127.0.0.1            lenovo                10:00           8/18/2019 6:00 PM      Eng
1                  lastname           127.0.0.2            apple                 2:30:00         8/18/2019 1:00 AM      Chn  
86                 user3              127.0.0.1            dell                                  8/18/2019 2:00 PM 
21                 user4              127.0.0.4            apple                 30:00           8/17/2019 1:00 PM      Eng
```

I want to first filter with a specific user who is connected for more than 30 minutes and then list its id.

**Update**

The result should be

```
1
21
```

because they are connected for 30min and over.

Comment: Is that you input or your required output? The link you gave also answers your questions in regards of filtering. What's your problem there?

Comment: Please show us what your array _really_ looks like. You are showing us some output, but from that we cannot say if the original array is an array of objects, or just lines of text with spaces and/or tabs in between the fields.

Comment: @vrdse I have edited and shown my desired output.

Comment: @Theo I have edited to have a better view. My question is the same as the link I shared, the only difference is that I can't create a table out of it. There are many other fileds which I have not shown.

Comment: Looks a lot nicer indeed, but.. this does not seem to be an array, just some textual _output_ of an array or table. We need to know what separates the fields, especially since some fields are empty. In your example the whitespaces are all space characters, so to me this looks like a Fixed-Width text file. Is that the case here?

Comment: Oh, this is from import-csv?

Comment: @Theo No, the spaces/tabs are not fixed.

Comment: @js2010 No, it is not.

Comment: @Manish We haven't heard from you.. So far, all you're saying is what the _array_ you're talking about is NOT. Time for you to explain to us what we are actualy looking at. As said, to me it looks like a Fixed-Width file where every column has a certain character width, but if it is something else, **what is it**?

Comment: @theo I can share you the actual data but I do not think we can send a message here. yes, data is tab-separated but not equal.

Comment: @Manish AHA, so Tab-delimited it is. That makes the code so much easier. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Theo ok, I'll check and update you the output.

Comment: @Theo the data given above is the output from another command can I replace your variable $text as $text = @"$original_output"@ -split '\r?\n'?

Comment: @Manish_ Ehh. no. I have edited the answer for that. In that case, you need to use **ConvertFrom-Csv** to convert the `$original_output` and use it.

Comment: @Theo the output which you have assigned in $text is not fixed hence I can't be sure what to input in $text variable. Can we read it from a file?

Comment: Please read the 3 answers I have given _carefully_. The first answer used `$text` as an _example_ of how to use it when the input is Fixed-Width. The first **Update** suggestion is for when your input is read from a TAB-delimited file. The second update suggestion (**OR**) is for when your input is in fact something you have gathered in a variable as output from some other command. Both the updated versions do NOT use the example in variable $text, but instead parse the data into variable `$table` straight away.

Comment: @Theo thanks. When I tried the solution then the output came like this: https://pastebin.com/UyJekU49 . The data actually looks like this: https://pastebin.com/50z69JLW

Comment: Then.. I wish you good luck my friend, because that data looks really screwy. The fields are NOT delimited by tabs, the columns are not aligned in any way. What produces such a mess, or is it manipulated somewhere in the process before you get it?

Comment: @Theo Thank you so much for you afford. I really appreciate it.
If I figure out a way to solve the issue, will let you know here.

Answer (score 1):

If the data you show is indeed the output of a Fixed-Width file, you need to try and get the widths for each field in order to parse it. A handicap here is that the original header names contain a space character and we need to replace that by an underscore.

For that, you can use the below function:

```
function ConvertFrom-FixedWith {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$Content
    )

    $splitter   = '§¤¶'             # some unlikely string: Alt-21, [char]164, Alt-20  
    $needQuotes = '^\s+|[",]|\s+$'  # quote the fields if needed

    function _FWClean ([string]$field) {
        # internal helper function to clean a field value with regards to quoted fields
        $field = $_.Trim() -replace '(?<!\\)\\"|""', '§DQUOTE¶'
        if ($field -match '^"(.*)"$')  { $field = $matches[1] }
        if ($field -match $needQuotes) { $field = '"{0}"' -f $field }
        return $field -replace '§DQUOTE¶', '""'
    }

    # try and calculate the field widths using the first header line
    # this only works if none of the header names have spaces in them
    # and where the headers are separated by at least one space character.

    Write-Verbose "Calculating column widths using first row"
    $row = ($Content[0] -replace '\s+', ' ').Trim()
    $fields = @($row -split ' ' ) # | ForEach-Object { _FWClean $_ })
    $ColumnBreaks = for ($i = 1; $i -lt $fields.Length; $i++) {
        $Content[0].IndexOf($fields[$i]) 
    }
    $ColumnBreaks = $ColumnBreaks | Sort-Object -Descending

    Write-Verbose "Splitting fields and generating output"
    $Content | ForEach-Object {
        if ($null -ne $_ -and $_ -match '\S') {
            $line = $_
            # make sure lines that are too short get padded on the right
            if ($line.Length -le $ColumnBreaks[0]) { $line = $line.PadRight(($ColumnBreaks[0] + 1), ' ') }
            # add the splitter string on every column break point
            $ColumnBreaks | ForEach-Object { 
                $line = $line.Insert($_, $splitter)
            }
            # split on the splitter string, trim, and dedupe possible quotes
            # then join using the delimiter character
            @($line -split $splitter | ForEach-Object { _FWClean $_ }) -join ','
        }
    } | ConvertFrom-Csv    # the result is an array of PSCustomObjects
}
```

With that function in place, parsing the text can be done like so:

```
$text = @"
Customer_ID        Client_Name        Computer_Name        Computer_Brand        Duration        Connection_Time        Lang
123                first last         127.0.0.1            lenovo                10:00           8/18/2019 6:00 PM      Eng
1                  lastname           127.0.0.2            apple                 2:30:00         8/18/2019 1:00 AM      Chn  
86                 user3              127.0.0.1            dell                                  8/18/2019 2:00 PM 
21                 user4              127.0.0.4            apple                 30:00           8/17/2019 1:00 PM      Eng
"@ -split '\r?\n'

# replace the single space characters in the header names by underscore
$text[0] = $text[0] -replace '(\w+) (\w+)', '$1_$2'

# the 'ConvertFrom-FixedWith' function takes a string array as input
$table = ConvertFrom-FixedWith -Content $text

#output on screen
$table | Format-Table -AutoSize

# export to CSV file
$table | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\test.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output (on screen)

```
Customer ID Client Name Computer Name Computer Brand Duration Connection Time   Lang
----------- ----------- ------------- -------------- -------- ---------------   ----
123         first last  127.0.0.1     lenovo         10:00    8/18/2019 6:00 PM Eng 
1           lastname    127.0.0.2     apple          2:30:00  8/18/2019 1:00 AM Chn 
86          user3       127.0.0.1     dell                    8/18/2019 2:00 PM     
21          user4       127.0.0.4     apple          30:00    8/17/2019 1:00 PM Eng
```

If your input $text is already a string array storing all the ines as we see them in your question, then leave out the `-split '\r?\n'`

---

Having parsed the input to a table of PsCustomObjects, you can get the customers that are connected for 30 minutes or more with the help of another small helper function:

```
function Get-DurationInMinutes ([string]$Duration) {
    $h, $m, $s = (('0:{0}' -f $Duration) -split ':' | Select-Object -Last 3)
    return [int]$h * 60 + [int]$m
}

($table | Where-Object { (Get-DurationInMinutes $_.Duration) -ge 30 }).Customer_ID
```

This will output

> ```
> 1
> 21
> ```

---

**Update**

---

Now that we finally know the data is from a TAB delimited CSV file, you don't need the `ConvertFrom-FixedWith` function.

Simply import the data using if it comes from a file

```
$table = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\customers.csv' -Delimiter "`t"
```

**Or**, if it comes from the output of another command as string or string array:

```
$table = $original_output | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t"
```

Then, use the `Get-DurationInMinutes` helper function just like above to get the Customer ID's that are connected for more than 30 minutes:

```
function Get-DurationInMinutes ([string]$Duration) {
    $h, $m, $s = (('0:{0}' -f $Duration) -split ':' | Select-Object -Last 3)
    return [int]$h * 60 + [int]$m
}

($table | Where-Object { (Get-DurationInMinutes $_.Duration) -ge 30 }).'Customer ID'
```

Comment: although my output is of different width I will try this out. Maybe it will solve the issue I am facing.
I'll update you the output once I try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Uhh.  I'm surprised there's not a canonical way to do this.  Based on https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/211ewa/how_to_convert_fixedwidth_to_pipedelimited_or/.

```
# 0                  19                 38                   59                    81              97                     120 123
# Customer ID        Client Name        Computer Name        Computer Brand        Duration        Connection Time        Lang
# 123                first last         127.0.0.1            lenovo                10:00           8/18/2019 6:00 PM      Eng
# 1                  lastname           127.0.0.2            apple                 2:30:00         8/18/2019 1:00 AM      Chn
# 86                 user3              127.0.0.1            dell                                  8/18/2019 2:00 PM
# 21                 user4              127.0.0.4            apple                 30:00           8/17/2019 1:00 PM      Eng


$cols = 0,19,38,59,81,97,120,123 # fake extra column at the end, assumes all rows are that wide

$firstline = get-content columns.txt | select -first 1
$headers = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $cols.count - 1; $i++) {
  $firstline.substring($cols[$i], $cols[$i+1]-$cols[$i]).trim()
}

# string Substring(int startIndex, int length)

$lines = Get-Content columns.txt | select -skip 1 
$lines | ForEach {
  $hash = [ordered]@{}
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $headers.length; $i++) {
    $hash += @{$headers[$i] = $_.substring($cols[$i], $cols[$i+1]-$cols[$i]).trim()}
  }
  [pscustomobject]$hash
}
```

Output:

```
PS /Users/js/foo> ./columns | ft

Customer ID Client Name Computer Name Computer Brand Duration Connection Time   Lan
----------- ----------- ------------- -------------- -------- ---------------   ---
123         first last  127.0.0.1     lenovo         10:00    8/18/2019 6:00 PM Eng
1           lastname    127.0.0.2     apple          2:30:00  8/18/2019 1:00 AM Chn
86          user3       127.0.0.1     dell                    8/18/2019 2:00 PM 
21          user4       127.0.0.4     apple          30:00    8/17/2019 1:00 PM Eng
```

Comment: I will try it out and update you the with the output.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a couple of requirements here.  I'm going to describe one way to do it using a generic 'for loop' and regular expression - something you can play with and tweak to your needs.  There are better ways of doing this (Powershell shortcuts), but based on the way you asked I'm going to assume that understanding is your goal, so this code should serve well if you have a background in any programming language.  Hope this helps!

```
# Here is your data formatted in an array.  Missing values are just empty fields.
# You could have fewer or more fields, but I've broken up your data into nine fields
# (0-8 when counting elements in an array)

# Customer ID, FName, LName, ComputerHostName, Brand, Duration, ConnectionDate, ConnectionTime, Lang
$myarray = @(
    ('123',  'firstname',    'lastname', '127.0.0.1', 'lenovo',  '10:00',    '8/18/2019', '6:00 PM', 'Eng'),
    ('1',    'lastnam',      '',         '127.0.0.2', 'apple',   '2:30:00',  '8/18/2019', '1:00 AM', 'Chn'),
    ('86',   'user3',        '',         '127.0.0.1', 'dell',    '04:33',    '8/18/2019', '2:00 PM', ''),
    ('21',   'user4',        '',         '127.0.0.4', 'apple',   '30:00',    '8/17/2019', '1:00 PM', 'Eng')
)

# This is a generic for loop that prints the ComputerHostName, which is the 4th column.
# The 4th column is column #3 if counting from zero (0,1,2,3)
# I'm using a regular expression to match duration above 30 minutes with the '-match' operator
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $myarray.Length; $i++ ) {
    if ( $myarray[$i][5] -match "[3-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]$" ){

        "$($myarray[$i][5]) - $($myarray[$i][3])"
    }
}
```

Printed Result:

```
2:30:00 - 127.0.0.2
30:00 - 127.0.0.4
```